# Find the location of ajax URL call on the server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, ajaxform

This is first time I heard about ajax. Right now I have a perfectly working script to plot data using `armcharts`. Source of this data seems to be `ajax` call and it goes like this.

```
$.ajax("myChannels/12").done( function(data) {
        createDeviceChart("chart", "Product Channels", ["Sensor1", "Senso2"], "Pulses", data);
```

I did `grep -R "myChannels/12" /`  on the server where this script is located. My present output is "No such device or address".

I did this on the browser: "IP address/myChannels/12" and I see JSON data in the dictionary format. How and where to locate source of this data? and script?

Comment: It looks like the URL is for myChannels and the channel I want is number 12, with the number being dynamic. So depending upon the backend, the endpoint may look something like "myChannels/{id}". Look for just myChannels and see what you find.

Answer (score 0):

(Newbie opinion) If you have access to the backend, where the service is deployed i.e. `myChannels`, it should be in the controllers assuming it is an MVC application.

Comment: suponiendo* que esta en MVC

Comment: Translated to English.